# Key derivation for AES-Encryption key and HMAC

Tags: encryption, aes, hmac, bcrypt, hkdf

Okay so I have two options for how I would derive two keys for AES encryption and HMAC they are as follows:

1. Run BCrypt on a users passphrase and then use the bouncy castle implementation of HKDF in java to extend the key from 31-bytes to 64-bytes before then splitting the result into two 32-byte keys.
2. Run Bcrypt twice on a users passphrase with a different salt and then use the bouncy castle implementation of HKDF in java to extend both keys from 31-bytes to 32-bytes.

My question is which way is better? (more secure)

Note: If you do have a answer please leave your reasoning in a way that is easy to understand.

Comment: 2. doesn't buy you anything, as the attacker only needs to break one. Also, can't bcrypt output 64 bytes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In both options, if the adversary has a way to check either AES key, then a brute password guessing attack can be attempted, and BCrypt is the main line of defense against that.

For constant effort, option 2 force to halve the *cost* parameter in BCrypt, and is thus twice more vulnerable to password guessing than option 1 is.

BCrypt's output is described as 31 byte, and likely has 192 bits of entropy excluding *cost* and *salt*. If so, this is more entropy than needed for security in the foreseeable future, and acceptable baring a <strike>diktat</strike> requirement that all keys have some larger size.

Thus **option 1 is decidedly the best** of the two; however a proper implementation of [scrypt](http://www.tarsnap.com/scrypt.html) would be considerably safer, and as a bonus there is no need for something extra in order to generate the desired amount of key material.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions I have decided on using SCrypt instead :)